# React router, prevent scroll to top when search param changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have list of links. When user click a link I render specific content in the page.

Problem:

When links are clicked and react-router push new search params, browser scrolls to page top.

Goal:

Keep page on the same position after param change